# Flutter - How to get frame of a Texture widget from iOS native plugin

Tags: ios, flutter, plugins, video-player

[video_player](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/main/packages/video_player/video_player) plugin is using [Texture](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Texture-class.html) to render a view with `textureId` that is registered from the ios platform code that holds the AVPlayer object.
In the Texture class document, it said:

```
The size of the rectangle is determined by its parent widget, and the texture is automatically scaled to fit.
```

In the native iOS code, How can detect the frame of the widget on the Flutter side to add a custom view as a subview into it?

Anyone who had tried to do that? Please advise. Thanks a lot.

Comment: We need to know the same.

Comment: Did you figure it out?